# Отправить email через консольное приложение Swift (Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, консоль

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь найти способ отправки email с помощью консольного приложения Swift. MessageUI недоступен. Пока единственный способ, который надумал, это отправив через приложение команду в терминал.

```
import Foundation
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "mail myemail@icloud.com"
task.arguments = ["-s", "This is my email"]
task.launch()
```

Ничего не выходит. Выдается следующее:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'

Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> launch path not accessible

Это потому, что `task.launchPath` это *путь* к программе, которую вы хотите запустить.

Например:

```
import Foundation

let task = Process()
let inputpipe = Pipe()

task.standardInput = inputpipe

task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/mail";
task.arguments = ["-s", "This is my email", "myemail@icloud.com"]
task.launch()

inputpipe.fileHandleForWriting.closeFile() // EOF
```

После вызова `mail` в нужно ввести тело письма и послать `EOF` для отправки (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> в консоли). Для этого можно использовать `fileHandleForWriting.closeFile`

Answer (score 1):

Можно также воспользоваться библиотекой [Swift-SMTP](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-SMTP)

Пример использования (взят из репозитория и дополнен для использования в консольном приложении)

```
import SwiftSMTP

let smtp = SMTP(
    hostname: "smtp.gmail.com",     // SMTP server address
    email: "user@gmail.com",        // username to login
    password: "password"            // password to login
)

let drLight = Mail.User(name: "Dr. Light", email: "drlight@gmail.com")
let megaman = Mail.User(name: "Megaman", email: "megaman@gmail.com")

let mail = Mail(
    from: drLight,
    to: [megaman],
    subject: "Humans and robots living together in harmony and equality.",
    text: "That was my ultimate wish."
)

smtp.send(mail) { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
}

var sending = true

smtp.send(mail) { (error) in

    sending = false

    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
}

while sending {
    sleep(1)
    print("sending")
}

print("done")
```